# Unity 2D mobile Game: How to make the world gravity follow device tilt

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I know it could be a basic question for Unity developers. But I am struggling to find answers for this problem. I want to move all objects in my game screen based on device acceleration. I only think of 2 possibles solutions:

1st: change the whole world gravity based on device tilt

2nd: apply the forces to all objects or change the velocity of all objects (I tried changing the velocity but the game got lagging)

Is there any good way to make 2D game objects smoothly move based on device tilt?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying `Physics2D.gravity`. It will change the gravity of all GameObjects in the scene.

`Physics2D.gravity = Input.acceleration * 50;` would have worked but because `Input.acceleration` has low, mid and high values, it wont work. So you can't assign  `Input.acceleration` directly to `Physics2D.gravity`.

You need to turn on you device then use `Debug.Log(Input.acceleration)` to view the low, middle and high values of each axis then you can use `if` statement and temporary `Vector2` value to get what 2D value to assign to `Physics2D.gravity`.

Also for any GameObject you want the accelerometer to affect **more**, **less** or **not at-all**, you can modify the `RigidBody Gravityscale` of that GameObject.

Comment: If I turn on device and use Debug.Log, can I assume that the values of Input.acceleration is not depend on which device I use? Those values can be applicable for any Android devices?

Comment: It is the-same on all Android and iOS devices. It wasn't before but Unity fixed it in 2012. So any value you get and clamp it will work for other mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

The gravity applied to all rigid bodies in the scene can be changed by setting `Physics2D.gravity`.

Note: Make sure you also set `rigidbody.useGravity = true` (for gravity to affect the objects).

Example:
Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(x, y);

[Physics.gravity Unity API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-gravity.html)

[Input-acceleration Unity API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the update() block of any element.

Physics2D.gravity is a "global" value that takes a Vector2 for value.

```
Debug.Log(Input.acceleration);
Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(Input.acceleration.x*1.5f, Input.acceleration.y*1.5f);
```

(You may edit/remove the multiplying floats in each input acceleration property, I added them just for some exponential gravity speed.)
Note: 
This will impact all the rigidbodies.